# SHParseDisplayName absolute pidl output build

Tags: windows, shell, com, namespaces

I am struggling to find out how the [“SHParseDisplayName”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shparsedisplayname) function builds the output absolute pidl.

I absolutely need to control its output.

To understand what I mean I make two examples:

Executing `SHParseDisplayName("C:\\Users\\Username\\Onedrive", IntPtr.Zero, out pidl, 0, out psfgaoOut)` the absolute "pidl" output variable is composed by these pidls (obtained by executing in sequence `SHGetNameFromIDList(pidl, SIGDN.PARENTRELATIVEPARSING, out name)` and `ILRemoveLastID(pidl)` until I reach the root):

1. ::{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}
2. Desktop

Executing the same for "C:\Users\Username\Pictures" the result is:

1. ::{24AD3AD4-A569-4530-98E1-AB02F9417AA8}
2. ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
3. Desktop

At first, I thought that the absolute pidl was composed based on the “pszParsingName” value of the [KNOWNFOLDER_DEFINITION](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-knownfolder_definition) of the relative known folder so I created a new known folder using [IKnownFolderManager::RegisterFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iknownfoldermanager-registerfolder) and setting a particular Shell namespace folder path in the “pszParsingName” value of the KNOWNFOLDER_DEFINITION.

Unfortunately the absolute pidl output was not the one expected. (And I added the new known folder path also in “user shell folders” registry key)

So I am asking your help to find out how I can control the building of the absolute pidl output of the “SHParseDisplayName” function.

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Why do you need to "control" its output? What are you trying to do? ids (lists) are opaque identifiers, the containing IShellFolder is reponsible from giving it to you (SHParseDisplayName calls that internally)  but it basically does what it wants. Sounds like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Because I found out that that value determines the particular namespace shell folder that is selected on the namespace tree when the user writes down a particular path in a file dialog or in win key + r dialog

Comment: Of course pidls are very important and used everywhere in the shell, but what are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: The previous answer should clarify the reason, I need to control what particular shell folder is selected on the namespace tree when a path is entered in a file dialog or in win key + r command

Comment: The folder selected is the one that SHParseDisplayName or equivalent gives back. What do you mean by "control" ?

Comment: By the examples I posted in my question one can understand that if the user types "C:\users\username\pictures" the pictures folder directly under "this pc" is selected on the namespace tree instead of, for example, the one under user profile root, that is exactly what I want to control.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by "I want to control that". You can't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207899/discussion-between-evolve-or-die-and-simon-mourier).

Comment: Simon, the system is clearly able to do that, I just need a way to do the same..